# How to make a new set of JTextFields appear on new line after the button has been clicked once

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, gridbaglayout

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class NewTextFields {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int width = 1200;
        final int height = 800;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton btn = new JButton("ADD Field");
        JTextField[] tfield = new JTextField[10];
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        panel.setSize(width, height);
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(panel);

        gbc.insets = new Insets(1,1,1,1);


        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    tfield[i] = new JTextField(5);

                    panel.add(tfield[i], gbc);
                    panel.revalidate();

                }

            }
        });

        panel.add(btn, gbc);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Im trying to test out certain things here if anyone can help me out i wanted to make abutton which creates a new set of JTexfields in a middle of the screen while a button in somewhere on side and after the line are created (max is 6) can i use a document listener on each line. Im new and i dont know how to do all that just asking if its possible.

Comment: Do you still need an answer for it ? If you found a solution you may post an answer to your own question.

Comment: im open to any suggestions as this is for my college project and im trying to get highest marks so i need to refine my code as much as i can to get highest marks.

Comment: I fear this might be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you care to explain what is the purpose of this line of `JTexfield`s it may encourage a different solution. Also please add the expected dynamic behavior of the `JButton` and `JTexfield`s. For example do you want them re centered whenever a new one is added ? Or do you want then enlightened to the left ?

Comment: Basically for this i just need a button which can create a row of JTextFields and i can use DocumentListener to get the inputs from boxes. I was trying to make it so when the button is pressed multiple times the new fields will be created under the old once with a space in between them with a max of 6 times so the user cannot create more than 6 rows of fields. If that makes sense?

Comment: All this information is in the original question. It does not add information about the dynamic behavior of the components (move up when a new one added  ?  do not move ?) nor the purpose of all this.

Comment: The purpose of this is for my college scoreboard project. When a new row gets added after the 1st 1 was created in the middle of screen the 1st row will move up or try making so both rows are kinda in middle of the screen.

Comment: Consider a [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)